# Get year and month from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date

I want to know how can I get the year and month into my database. For example, suppose it’s August, 2011. The output that I need is like this: `CAB 11 08 001` (CAB + YEAR + MONTH + CURRENT NO. in tracking number. )

This is my SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateTrackNo] AS
Declare @tempYear VARCHAR(5),@tempMonth VARCHAR(5)
Set @tempYear = Year(GetDate())
Set @tempMonth = Month(GetDate())
SELECT 'CAB' + Right(Cast(Year(GetDate()) as varchar(10)),2)+ Right(Cast(Month(GetDate()) as varchar(10)),2) + Right('000000'+ Cast(CurrentNo as varchar(10)), 5) from tblTrackNo where GenYear = @tempYear
--UPDATE tblTrackNo SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 where GenYear = @tempYear
```

The output for this is `CAB1180035`, but I need `CAB1108035`. I need to put zero(0) 08 like this for the month.

In my table I have only genYear and Current No. Do I need to add another column for MONTH?

Comment: This kind of formatting is normally better done in client code (on the vb.net side) rather than storing the or calculating the formatted value on the sql side.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're making separate columns for YEAR, MONTH, etc.

Most (all?) DBMSs I'm aware of have a `Date` type.  Use it.  They put a lot of useful stuff in it, like accepting date inputs in different formats and giving them as output in pretty much any format you can think of.

For example, if you have a `DT` column of type `Date` in Oracle, you can output month as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DT, "MM") FROM MYTABLE;
```

and the month will always be displayed as 2 digits (01, 02, ... 12)

Comment: Ok thank's for that .. but how can i add 0(zero)  in month .. like this.. 08 becauuse the only output that i have is .. 118 MEANING year 2011 and month of august (8)..

Comment: for my last questions regarding the year and the time. . i want to know that everytime i change the month the tracking number will start to 001 .. for example this is my tracking number.. CAB1108072 == CAB + 11 for year, 08 for month of august, 072 running number... DO I NEED TO HAVE ANOTHER COLUMN IN TABLE FOR MONTH? to generate the trackingn number everytime the month change ..the output like this.. EXAmple.. August 31, 2011 running number is 072 tomorrow is september 1st i need the tracking number start to 001 .. because september is another month ..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    'CAB'
    + RIGHT(YEAR(GetDate()),2)
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(GetDate())),2)
    + Right('00000' + Cast(CurrentNo as varchar(10)), 5)
```

That might work..

Comment: for my last questions regarding the year and the time. . i want to know that everytime i change the month the tracking number will start to 001 .. for example this is my tracking number.. CAB1108072 == CAB + 11 for year, 08 for month, 072 running number... DO I NEED TO HAVE ANOTHER COLUMN IN TABLE FOR MONTH? to generate the trackingn number everytime the month change ..Do i need to add another column for month? the output like this.. EXAmple.. August 31, 2011 running number is 072 tomorrow is september 1st i need the tracking number start to 001 .. because september is another month ..

Answer (score 0):

Using your method \ logic..

```
Right('0' + Cast(Month(GetDate()) as varchar(10)),2)
```