# About tracking number..

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get year and month from SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251916/get-year-and-month-from-sql)

I want to know that everytime I change the month the tracking number will start at 001 ..
For example this is my tracking number:
`CAB1108072 == CAB + 11 for year, 08 for month of august, 072 running number`

**Do I need to have another column in the table for the month in order to generate the tracking number everytime the month changes?**

The output should be like this.
 Example:

- August 31, 2011 running number is 072 tomorrow is september 1st i
  need the tracking number start to 001, because september is another
  month.

This is my SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateTrackNo] AS
Declare @tempYear VARCHAR(5)
Set @tempYear = Year(GetDate())
SELECT 'CAB' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112),3,4) + Right('0000000'+ Cast(CurrentNo as varchar(10)),3) FROM tblTrackNo where GenYear = @tempYear
UPDATE tblTrackNo SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 where GenYear = @tempYear
```

My table tblTrackNo has two column names, `genYear  Numeric(18,0)` and `CurrentNo  Numeric(18,0)`

Do I need to add another column for month?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Numeric` for your column datatypes?  Since you're building a string, I'd recommend storing them as CHAR to save casting:

```
genYear CHAR(2)
CurrentNo INT
CurrentMonth CHAR(2)
```

Leave CurrentNo as INT for ease of incrementing.

The SP below (note, I haven't tested the code, so there may be some things you'll need to tweak) does the following:

```
1.  Sets up variables to hold the 2 digit year and 2 digit month (based on the current date) as CHAR(2).
2.  Gets the record for the current year.
3.  If there is no record for the current year, it generates the tracking number and inserts a new record (for the current year) into the table
3.  If there is a record for the current year, but the month in the table is different than the current month, it generates the tracking number starting at 001.  Otherwise, it generates the next tracking number.
3A.  It then updates the table.
4.  Finally, it returns the tracking number
```

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateTrackNo] AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @curYear AS CHAR(2),
            @curMonth AS CHAR(2)

    DECLARE @dbYear AS CHAR(2),
            @dbMonth AS CHAR(2),
            @dbNumber AS CHAR(3),
            @newNumber AS INT,
            @trackingNumber AS CHAR(10)

    -- Set up the values for the current year and current moth
    SET @curYear = RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR), 2)
    SET @curMonth = CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
    -- Use REPLICATE to pad with a leading 0, if needed
    SET @curMonth = REPLICATE('0', 2 - DATALENGTH(@curMonth)) + @curMonth

    -- Get the current values from the database for the current year
    SELECT @dbYear = genYear,
           @dbMonth = currentMonth,
           @dbNumber = CAST(CurrentNumber AS VARCHAR)
    FROM   tblTrackNo
    WHERE  genYear = @curYear

    IF (@dbYear IS NOT NULL)
        -- There was a record for the current year
        BEGIN
            IF (@dbMonth != @currMonth)
                -- We're in a new month
                BEGIN
                    SET @newNumber = 2
                    SET @trackingNumber = 'CAB' + @curYear + @curMonth + '001'
                END
            ELSE
                -- We're in the current month
                BEGIN
                    -- Pad with apprpriate number of leading 0's
                    SET @dbNumber = REPLICATE('0', 3 - DATALENGTH(@dbNumber) + @dbNumber
                    SET @trackingNumber = 'CAB' + @curYearChar + @curMonthChar + @dbNumber
                    SET @newNumber = CAST(@dbNumber AS INT)
                END

            -- Update the table accordingly
            UPDATE tblTrackNo
            SET    CurrentNo = @newNumber,
                   CurrentMonth = @curMonth
            WHERE  genYear = @curYear
         END
     ELSE
         -- We don't have a record in the table for the current year
         BEGIN
             -- Create the tracking number
             SET @trackingNumber = 'CAB' + @curYear + @curMonth + '001'

             -- Insert a new record into the table
             INSERT INTO tblTrackNo(
                         genYear,
                         CurrentNo,
                         CurrentMonth
             )
             SELECT      @curYear,
                         2,
                         @curMonth
         END

    SELECT @trackingNumber AS trackingNumber
END
```

This is most likely not the most efficient SP, but it will do the job.  You also might want to consider moving the logic out of the DB and having the application take care of generating the tracking number based on the data returned from your table, and then the application can update (or insert) as appropriate.