# SQL to generate new sequential identifiers when current month changes?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateTrackNo] AS
   DECLARE @tempYear VARCHAR(5),@tempMonth VARCHAR(5)

   SET @tempYear = Year(GetDate())
   SET @tempMonth = Month(GetDate())

   SELECT 'CAB' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 3, 4) + 
          RIGHT('0000000'+ CAST(CurrentNo AS VARCHAR(10)), 5) 
   FROM tblTrackNo 
   WHERE GenYear = @tempYear

   UPDATE tblTrackNo 
   SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 
   WHERE GenYear = @tempYear
```

My problem here is I don't know how to reset a tracking number to `001` everytime I change the MONTH.. in my sql code its working when the year change...

Example ..this is my tracking number.. `CAB1108031` 11 is for year 08 is for month.. when I change the month the output that I need is  `CAB1109001` if the month choose for the first time if not the tracking number 031 will stay and add up to the end.. thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain your problem a little bit more. And re-tag this appropriately as this is `SQL` only, not `VB.Net`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251916/get-year-and-month-from-sql

Comment: @Jim – I think that other question was more like the predecessor to this one. I don't think they're really duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change both your `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries to include the month. You might also need to add a column for storing the month to the table `tblTrackNo` if there isn't already one in that table.

Example (T-)SQL:

```
SELECT  'CAB' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 3, 4) + 
        RIGHT('0000000'+ CAST(CurrentNo AS VARCHAR(10)), 5) 
FROM tblTrackNo 
WHERE   GenYear = @tempYear
        AND GenMonth = @tempMonth

UPDATE tblTrackNo 
SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 
WHERE   GenYear = @tempYear
        AND GenMonth = @tempMonth
```

As-is, you're effectively generating tracking numbers based only on the current year.

You will probably also need to add data to the table `tblTrackNo`, to at least initialize the tracking numbers for each year and number. Or you could use (T-)SQL like the following:

```
SELECT  'CAB' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 3, 4) + 
        RIGHT('0000000'+ CAST(ISNULL(CurrentNo, 1) AS VARCHAR(10)), 5) 
FROM tblTrackNo
WHERE   GenYear = @tempYear
        AND GenMonth = @tempMonth

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tblTrackNo
    WHERE   GenYear = @tempYear
            AND GenMonth = @tempMonth )

    UPDATE tblTrackNo 
    SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 
    WHERE   GenYear = @tempYear
            AND GenMonth = @tempMonth

ELSE

    INSERT tblTrackNo ( GenYear, GenMonth, CurrentNo )
    VALUES ( @tempYear, @tempMonth, 2 );
```

Comment: so i will add another column for MONTH? what will i need to put to the fields in table??.. thanks.. because i have only two column name  in my tblTrackNo the genYear and the currentNo

Comment: +1 makes a lot more sense - I couldn't see the forest for the trees.... but this approach should work just fine! Great answer